# There *are* a house in New Orleans. Why "are"? Where many poor boys to destruction *has* gone. Why "has"?

Tags: lyrics

On this 1933 recording

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=147kS8O59Qs

Clarence Ashley clearly sings

```
There are a house in New Orleans
They call the Rising Sun
Where many poor boys to destruction has gone
And me, oh God, for one
```

"There **are** a house in New Orleans" and "many poor boys to destruction **has** gone".

So what "are" and "has" are doing there? What's going on with plurals in this text?

Mother wiki [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarence_Ashley#Early_life): "Ashley was born ... in Bristol, Tennessee in 1895, the only child of George McCurry and Rose-Belle Ashley". That doesn't suggest English is not his native tongue.

Is it a dialect?

Comment: That is pretty weird. But yes, totally a native speaker, kind of a backwoods country accent. I have a hard time imagining those two uses are natural though.

Comment: Song lyrics (and poetry) often cannot be be analyzed in terms of grammar.

Comment: I hear _**They** are a house_, which is still strange, but not ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

(Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Rising_Sun#Origin):

> "House of Rising Sun" was said to have been known by miners in
>   1905.[6] The oldest published version of the lyrics is that printed by Robert Winslow Gordon in 1925, in a column "Old Songs That Men Have
>   Sung" in Adventure magazine.[9] The lyrics of that version
>   begin:[9][10]
>
> ```
> There is a house in New Orleans, it's called the Rising Sun
>
> It's been the ruin of many poor girl
>
> Great God, and I for one.
> ```

The version in your recording is intentionally rendered "illiterate", to sound more "country", and possibly to hint at an African-American origin.

Comment: "of many poor girl", not "girls" :-( Oh my. So you think this is done on purpose.

Comment: Understand that the quoted lyric was transcribed from oral, and very likely an "a" before "poor" was weakly voiced.